# Find list of active users in UNIX

Tags: unix, solaris

Get the list of active users[ users who has connected atleast once in last 6 months] in Solaris.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could solve this by creating a script that date stamps a file somewhere when any user logs in. it could be run by the shell's system-wide init (/etc/profile for bourne compatible shells)

for instance, create a directory called `/var/log/logintimes` and have /etc/profile run `touch /var/logintimes/$USER`

then, to see the last login time,  do `ls -l /var/logintimes`